# Command argument in Tkinter python not working with lambda

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

Hello I am making a function that changes the image of a button of Tkinter in python and my code is something like this:

```
def place(button):
    if result == 'Wrong':
        button.config(image=wrong_img)
    elif result == "Correct":
        button.config(image=correct_img)


button1 =  Button(root,image=button_img,borderwidth=2,command=lambda: place(button1),highlightthickness=0)
button1.place(x=10,y=10)

button2 = Button(root,image=button_img,borderwidth=2,command=lambda: place(button),highlightthickness=0)
button2.place(x=200,y=10)
```

I have tried using this. It doesn't give any error but runs without even pressing the button.

```
button1 = Button(root,image=button_img,boderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0)
button1.command = place(button1)
```

Thank You for your time!!

Comment: `button1['command'] = lambda: place(button1)` is the way it should be, but what is `wrong_img` and `correct_img` and why doesnt your first set of code work?

Comment: @CoolCloud it gives an error of UnboundLocalError: local variable button1 referenced before assignment

Comment: No where in your code is `current_player` mentioned. Try to include a example we can run and see

Comment: @CoolCloud Yeah Thanks i was doing mistake in  `button1['command'] = lambda: place(button1)`instead of that I used  `button1.command = lambda : place(button1)`which was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that instead of
`button1.command = lambda: place(button1)`
I should use
`button1['command'] = lambda: place(button1)`

Comment: Also `if result = 'Wrong'` should be `if result == 'Wrong'`.

Comment: @acw1668 oh yeah that was a typo